# How to catch item changes on list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I have created state workflow in Sharepoint.

My idea is:

1/ when workflow is started create copy of list item on which workflow was started, this copy is created to another web list within current site collection - that's working

2/ monitor changes on parent item and propagate them to copied item - that's working

3/ monitor changes on copied item and propagate them back to original item - that's not working

I was trying to use [IListItemService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.ilistitemservice_members.aspx), but apparently it canno watch for changes on different then current web ? Is there any other way how to do it ?

I was thinking about SharePoint 2010 Pluggable Workflow Services - but in my class which derives from SPWorkflowExternalDataExchangeService method CallEventHandler was called twice even when only one call of SPWorkflowExternalDataExchangeService.RaiseEvent was made (this was called from custom event receiver) - another problem with this solution is when I recycle app pool I lost my singleton class which is responsible for maintaining list of state information needed for RaiseEvent method.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event mechanism built into SharePoint just for this purpose. There's no need to use workflows or copy items.

[Example: Creating a List Item Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx)